# Would it be possible to use Robotium with Espresso?

Tags: android, robotium, android-espresso

It is technically possible to use Robotium along with Espresso?

I know that Espresso is using a custom Test Runner, `GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner`, but as it is just an extension of the default test runner, would Robotium work along with Espresso?

And if so, what would be the lower grade of integration possible?

Would it be possible to use them in different methods of a same test class or I would need separate classes?

Comment: GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner doesn't actually extend the default test runner InstrumentationTestRunner, it is a parallel implementation that uses a few hidden methods from android.app.Instrumentation that "normal" sub classes of Instrumentation don't have available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible. While Espresso requires the `GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner`, that runner works fine with any kind of tests based on `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<>`, independent of the framework being used on top.

You can have Espresso and Robotium test methods in the same class, technically you could use them even side by side in the same test method. They are conceptually very different though, so there is little benefit in using them side by side.

Either framework is capable of what the other can do. Generally it makes more sense to choose one and then stick with it, because when writing multiple automated tests, one will build an utility infrastructure to limit code duplication and keeping the test maintainable. Using two frameworks doubles this effort.

Comment: I would recommend Espresso over Robotium due to execution speed, stability, and architectural clarity that clearly defines the extension points.